# What is the proper way to move android studio project from one computer to another

Tags: java, android, import, dex, android-multidex

Hi guys I have created an android studio 2.1 project on my laptop sometime ago and have gotten pretty far with it. I now have a desktop PC that I would LOVE to put my project onto and continue development on. Everything builds just fine on the laptop but when i copy over the entire project over to my desktop it keeps giving me an error for the dex file being over 64k which is clearly not the case on my laptop. I believe im moving the project over to the desktop wrong. I tried many different ways but always get errors when doing so, the closes I got was when I went on my desktop and opened just the gradle.build file in android studio and let it load the project from there. But as stated earlier I get the "dex file exceeds 64k methods". Any help is appreciated.

[dex error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPJuj.jpg)

Comment: Did you try git? github.com

Comment: Git is the way to go.

Comment: Github would be great for this, if you're a student, I think you get 7 free private repos but don't quote me on that.

Comment: The right way?  Upload all your non-generated files to your version control system and redownload from there.  If you aren't using version control, you should be.

Comment: Use Git based solution like `Bitbucket`. Its totally free. You can create new account. Also if you provide logcat then maybe you could get help. Create a repository and in Android Studio -> Enable VCS

Comment: Wow thank you so much for all of the quick replys!! I dont know much about GIT which im sure have to very soon lol, but I know subversion very well so I set that up, I then enabled VCS on my project on the laptop, then did integrate project. I wasnt able to commit anything but I guess it went through cause on my Desktop I did checkout from subversion and it worked but I still get the dex error exceeds 64k. Any ideas as to why I am getting this? did I not merge my project into subversion correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the git repository account and clone it from git repository on other system .

use the multidexEnabled option as true in build.gradle to avoid the multidexing issues

Comment: UPDATE: I did not get it to sync over, for some reason, it was syncing over a ton of files that are PC specific (eg.paths to SDK and such) but I been adding those to the ignore list as they conflict between commits and updates. I got a work around by creating a blank project and adding it to svn then adding in my code and committing every now and then. Sorry guys I know this isnt the best but its what I did to hurry things along to get it going. If someone finds a better solution please post it or guide me to what i did wrong. im accepting this answer for now till a better one comes along.